# Editing the listed hudson java system info

Tags: java, ubuntu, hudson

I am aware that Hudson can use different versions of Java to compile projects. What I am looking for however, is to edit the version hudson lists on its SystemInfo page:

> java.endorsed.dirs
>   java.ext.dirs
>  java.home
>   java.io.tmpdir
>   java.library.path
>   java.runtime.name
>   java.runtime.version

Those things. Currently, OpenJDK is listed. I have previously installed the regular Java 6.021 JDK from sun itself. I want to make it so that is listed, and not OpenJDK. OpenJDK was installed along with Hudson, for some reason.

The problem is that I can't find any of this in the config files. Where do I set this?

Also, I have modified the PATH variables and the /etc/bash.bashrc file to have respectively the correct paths and the JAVA_HOME variable. These have been tested and confirmed in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following link (`ls -l /usr/bin/java`):

`/usr/bin/java`

What does it point to? My guess is it is pointing to the OpenJDK java executable.

You have to make it point to your Sun JDK java executable: `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` (put full path of `$JAVA_HOME` here.

`cd /usr/bin && ln -sf $JAVA_HOME/bin/java .`

(have to do this as root, and again substitute full path instead of $JAVA_HOME)

Answer (score 0):

These settings come from the JVM that Hudson is running under. If these settings are reporting OpenJDK, then somehow your environment variable changes must not have taken effect.

Make sure that that JAVA_HOME change is visible to Hudson, and that the Sun JDK appears on the PATH before any OpenJDK directory.